# How to measure how much traffic a server could potentially handle?

Tags: traffic-measurement

Are there any tools that would enable me to load-test my server and tell me how much traffic it could roughly handle?

By traffic I mean how many requests per second it can consistently serve without timing out.

I realize that every server is different, and so is every application that runs on that server. That's why I thought this route may be the way to go.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a very simple benchmark on web servers (if your request is the same every time), you could use [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). A very simple tool, but it gives some interesting statistics nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind going the paid software route, then LoadRunner is a very good choice, IMO.

I have used [LoadRunner](http://www.mercury.com/us/products/performance-center/loadrunner/) in the past for doing this kind of measurement for multiple web  and non web applications.

Answer (score 0):

And I like [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/). The only downside (but I don't know if others are able to do this) is that it doesn't replay well the ASP.NET hugely long generated URLs